# Elastic Search Query based in subdocuments filters

Tags: elasticsearch, etl, dsl

I'm working in a small personal project that requires to make some queries in ElasticSearch, and I wanted to ask you for some advise because I'm kind of stuck.

This is the issue:
So far I have a index that contains a type called users. It stores an email and array of events done by that user.

```
{
   {
      email : account1@gmail.com
      events : [
            {
                 type: 'SOLVE PROBLEM'
                 date : 20160402
             }, 
            {
                 type: 'RESPOND QUESTION'
                 date : 20160402
             },
             {
                  type: 'ASK QUESTION'
                  date : 20160403
            },
             {
                 type: 'SOLVE PROBLEM'
                 date : 20160509
             },
             {
                 type: 'ASK QUESTION'
                 date : 20160402
             },
           ...

       ],
   },
   {
      email : account2@gmail.com
      events : [
            {
                 type:  'RESPOND QUESTION'
                 date : 20160402
             }, 
            {
                 type: 'RESPOND QUESTION'
                 date : 20160402
             },
             {
                  type: 'ASK QUESTION'
                  date : 20160402
            },
             {
                 type: 'SOLVE PROBLEM'
                 date : 20160402
             },
             {
                 type: 'ASK QUESTION'
                 date : 20160402
             },
           ...

       ],
   },
-....
}
.....
```

I'd like to make queries based in the number of events done by each user, something like:

- Return me all the users(documents) that have "responded" more than 5 questions
- Return all the users that have "solved" 4  problems during 2016-01-01 and 2016-02-04
- Return all the users that have asked less than 4 questions
- Return me all the users(documents) that have "responded" more than 5 questions AND that have "solved" 4  problems during 2016-01-01 and 2016-02-04

The values come from a facet.

I'd like to ask you if you can give me some advice about which filter/aggs do I need to use in order to filter a document based in the number of elements in a subdocument.

Because I have been reading about how make it but I have not been able do to do it yet, and even worst, I'm not sure if it is possible, because I read that ES doesn't have a HAVING clause like in SQL

Thank you for any help or advice.